# How do I hide font sample characters entered in the flash sifr.fla?

Tags: sifr

How do I hide font sample characters I entered in the flash sifr.fla to make my font.swf file? I entered "I" and now "I" shows up behind the text I'm replacing in the background. Is this a matter of simple making the sample character the same color as the background I'll be using or is there another way to do this so that I don't have to create a new font.swf every time I use a different background color? Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Those characters should be replaced straight away, before the movie even shows up. This sounds indicative of another error, are you sure the ActionScript etc was exported correctly?

Comment: Hi Mark I've double checked all of my publishing settings. I'm using the latest version of Flash, and it doesn't have the "upload from bottom" setting. Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: "upload from bottom"?

What do you get when you open the Flash movie itself in Firefox? It should say "Rendered with sIFR 3…".